# Amazon Web Services IDE setup

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ide

I am trying to connect to the Ubuntu 14.04 IDE I have launched on Amazon Web Services. I am using the EC2 Instance Connect (browser-based SSH connection) method to connect. I don't get an error message, but all that happens is that a blank window opens (image attached). The same thing happens when I try to connect through Windows and Ubuntu. Can anybody steer me in the right direction?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you are trying to connect to your Amazon EC2 instance.

[Refer to the AWS User Guide on EC2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-connect-methods.html).

### EC2 Instance Connect

[Install EC2 Instance Connect](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-connect-set-up.html), then connect to your instance

```
$ mssh i-001234a4bf70dec41EXAMPLE
```

### Using SSH

Generate your SSH key

```
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

Push your SSH key to the EC2 instance

```
$ aws ec2-instance-connect send-ssh-public-key --region us-west-2 --instance-id i-001234a4bf70dec41EXAMPLE --availability-zone us-west-2b --instance-os-user ec2-user --ssh-public-key ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Log in to your EC2 Instance

```
$ ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa ec2-user@ec2-198-51-100-1.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```